# How do you script/format a YAML file to add a new line above root level elements?

Tags: bash, shell, perl, yaml

I have a YAML file for a Ruby on Rails configuration that is formatted like the below

```
default: &default
  api:
    my_id: test
    my_secret: test
development:
  <<: *default
  api:
    domain: some domain
  sso:
    url: some_url
qa:
  <<: *default
  api:
```

I would like to write a script that will add a new line above all the top level elements.  So for instance when the script or command runs against the above, it would produce

```
default: &default
  api:
    my_id: test
    my_secret: test

development:
  <<: *default
  api:
    domain: some domain
  sso:
    url: some_url

qa:
  <<: *default
  api:
```

However when I run this command

```
perl -pi -e 's/^^[ ](.*)$/\n$1/g' yamlfile.yml
```

It adds a new line above every line, not just the root elements.  What would be the proper way to add such a new line above only the top level elements?

Comment: Did you mean `^[^ ]` which means "beginning of line + not space", instead of `^^[ ]` which means "beginning of line + beginning of line + space"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should achieve what you wanted :

```
perl -pi -e 's/^\S/\n$&/' yamlfile.yml
```

Answer (score 2):

`^^` is redundant, and `[ ]` is the opposite of what you want to match. I think you meant `^[^ ]`, which is better, but inserts a line at the top of the file.

Solution:

```sh
perl -i -pe's/^(?=\S)/\n/ if $. != 1' yamlfile.yml
```

A solution that reads in the whole file at once:

```sh
perl -i -0777pe's/\n\K(?=\S)/\n/g' yamlfile.yml
```

Neither of the above checks if there's an existing blank line. The following, on the other hand, normalizes blank lines precending top-level elements:

```sh
perl -i -0777pe's/^\n+//; s/\n\K\n*+(?=\S)/\n/g' yamlfile.yml
```